# Sum of Multiples in Scheme

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, tail-recursion

so I am very new to Scheme and functional programming as a whole.
I am trying to write a program that finds the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000. 
This is my attempt so far :

```
(define (sum-of-multiples n)
; Start = 0, End = n, Sum = 0.
(get-sum 0 n 0)
)

; A recursive loop that starts at 0 and ends with given n (1000).
(define (get-sum start end sum)
   (cond
   ; Stopping case.
   ((= start end) sum)
   ; If start counter is divisible by 3, add to sum.
   ((= (remainder start 3) 0) (get-sum (+ start 1) end (+ start sum)))
   ; If start counter is divisible by 5, add to sum.
   ((= (remainder start 5) 0) (get-sum (+ start 1) end (+ start sum)))
   ; Otherwise just increment start counter.
   (get-sum (+ start 1) end sum))
)

(display (sum-of-multiples 1000))
(display " ")
```

I am not sure if the thing wrong with my code at the moment is because of Scheme syntax issues or my attempt at recursion to solve the problem.
As I am not great at either of those things.

When I run this code I just get '0' displayed.

Any help with finding and fixing my errors would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cond` format is:

```
(cond (<condition> <expr>)
       .
       .
      (else <expr>))
```

In your code there is no `else`. `get-sum` function (with some reformatting) should be:

```
(define (get-sum start end sum)
   (cond
      ((= start end) sum)
      ((= (remainder start 3) 0)
       (get-sum (+ start 1) end (+ start sum)))
      ((= (remainder start 5) 0)
       (get-sum (+ start 1) end (+ start sum)))
      (else
       (get-sum (+ start 1) end sum))))
```

With this fix, your code displays `233168`. I didn't check your algorithm, but this result looks better than `0` :)

Comment: Ah awesome! Thank you :D

Answer (score 4):

You left out the `else` on the "all other cases" case; it should be

```
(else (get-sum (+ start 1) end sum))
```

An attempt at explaining where you got 0 from:

A `cond` clause has the form `(condition expression)`, so your condition is `get-sum`.
Just like `else`, this condition is never false.

There is also an implicit `begin` after the condition, so what you have is equivalent to

```
(else (begin (+ start 1) end sum))
```

And the result of that is the value of the last expression in the `begin` block, which is `sum`.

Since `sum` is 0 when you reach that condition for the first time, the result is 0.